# ~= operator in Matlab

Tags: matlab, operators

Does anyone know what the operator ~= in Matlab? I have seen it in an if statement

```
if currsign ~= 0
[

]
```

Not equal to?

Comment: correct. 6 more to go...

Comment: I searched for "matlab operators" and found http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/relationaloperators.html

Comment: I searched for "matlab operators" and found http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html#f0-38145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means "not equal"

For example:

```
1 ~= 1 % Returns false

1 ~= 2 % Returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab ~= is not equal to. the brackets following the if are not valid Matlab syntax though. 'if' needs to be paired with an 'end'